# Redirect admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Hello I dont know why and where problem, but when i try to register or login or someting its redirect me Admin Panel, what i can do for leave this? can you help me with this problem? what file i need to change?

admin controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Session;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->input();
            if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])) {
                Session::put('adminSession',$data['email']);
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
            }
        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Session::has('adminSession'))
        {

        }else{
            return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_error', 'Please login to access');
        }
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function settings()
    {
        return view('admin.settings');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_success', 'Logged out Successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `return view('admin.dashboard')`, within the `dashboard` method, are out of the if else statement, so it will always return the admin dashboard view

Comment: its not this maybe in other file

Comment: It's possibly a middleware issue that maybe redirecting.
Also please check there must a duplicate route name in web.php i had the same infinite redirect issue when two routes had exact same name.
So Please verify route list

Comment: thanks its in file RedirectIfAuthenticated i add something need to remove thiis )))